# Find and replace all strings with a certain length JavaScript/Google Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I am a JavaScript/GoogleScript Rookie, so please bear with me. I am trying to create a Script in Google Docs that will be able to locate all instances of words having exactly 10 characters and append an element to them which would in turn give me a url.

Example : Here is my link pineapples

I would like to find the 10 character string, being pineapple, and add google.com/ in front of each of the strings that have a length of 10.

Giving me "Here is my link google.com/pineapples."

```
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById(str.length=10); 
var res = str.replace("str.length=10", "br"+"str.length=10");
```

This seems completely wrong, but all I can come up with for now.

Comment: It looks as if you need `.replace(/\b\w{10}\b/g, "google.com/$&")`. However, if you need to only handle "words" that are in fact non-whitespace chunks, use a split-join approach that is more straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

1. **Split your string** using space as a separator (this will give you an array)
2. **Test the length** of each part in a loop
3. **Prepend `google.com/`** if a part has 10 characters
4. **Join your array** and enjoy your transformed string

```js
var str = "Here is my link pineapples",
    arr = str.split(' ');
    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].length === 10) {
    arr[i] = 'google.com/' + arr[i];
  }
}

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by using a Regex and then using a backreference to refer to the matching group.

**Regex:** `(\S{10})` 
it has 3 parts

1. `\S` matches anything other than a space, tab or newline.
2. `{10}` matches the above character exactly 10 times.
3. `()` is the Capturing Group, which is used later in the regex `$1`.

You can get more information [here](https://regex101.com/r/6sk9jv/1) which explain the above Regex in detail.

You may change it to fit your need.

```js
var stringVal = "Here is my link pineapples";
var stringReplaced = stringVal.replace(/(\S{10})/, "google.com/$1");
console.log(stringReplaced);
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay so bear with me, but my idea is as follows:
The text that you want to replace, are they all within elements of the same class? If so, you could do something like this (jQuery hope you don't mind)

```
function myFunction(){
  $('myClass').each(function(){
    var innerText = $(this).text();
    var substring = innerText.substr(0,9);
    $(this).text(substring);
  }
}
```